# How I can open a browser half of the screen in my mobile using angular and ionic framework

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

How I can open a browser half of the screen in my mobile using the angular and ionic framework as like youtube player. The video will play in 40 % of the screen and rest the content will display.

Answer (score 0):

You may divide your UI for two blocks (2/3 proportion or any other), but not open a browser as a part of mobile screen